# Vanilla JavaScript in Svelte

Tags: javascript, svelte

I've been following a guide to collapse a sidebar. I realised that I cannot use the `$` because it's reserved in Svelte. Can someone guide me on how to make this work? Thanks :)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#sidebarCollapse').on('click', function () {
        $('#sidebar').toggleClass('active');
    });
});
```

Comment: The $ comes from jQuery, not vanilla js.

Comment: I think he's asking how to convert it to vanilla JS, but I might be wrong. @James, can you clarify?

Comment: you can use `jQuery.noConflict()`

Comment: I'm sorry yeah. How would I go about adding the '. Active'  class without jquery or can I use the '$' in Svelte somehow?

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/#jQuery-noConflict-removeAll

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should really read through/follow along with the [Svelte tutorial](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/basics), it might help you better understand how to overcome small challenges like this.

Toggling a class is as easy as toggling a variable and using Svelte's [shorthand class directive](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/class-shorthand)

```
<script>
    let active = false;
</script>

<button on:click={()=> active = !active}>
    Some menu text or an icon here
</button>

<aside class:active>
    I'm a sidebar
</aside>
```

Then you just make the styles equal to whatever tutorial you're following along with since the active class would be conditionally applied at that point.

Here's a simple [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/e85cdaba377341c181134646c6df69ce?version=3.18.2) example.

Answer (score 3):

The equivalent vanilla js code would be:

```
const sidebarCollapse = document.getElementById('sidebarCollapse');
const sidebar = document.getElementById('sidebar');

sidebarCollapse.onclick = () => sidebar.classList.toggle('active');
```